# Define default value to a variable

Tags: vimscript, neovim

I want to assign an expression to a variable, and if it has no value, use some default.

On almost every programming language I can use something like:

```
let linked_hl_id = hlID(l:linked_group) || 114
```

But of course it does not work, and the option I found is this eyesore using ternary and 2 lines of assignment:

```
let linked_hl_id = hlID(l:linked_group)
let linked_hl_id = linked_hl_id ? linked_hl_id : 114
```

What is a better syntax for that?
Using NVIM `v0.4.4`.

Thanks.

Comment: @BLayer I love ternary, but I wonder if those 2 lines can be compacted to 1.

Comment: Ah, okay. :) I misinterpreted what you are conveying.

Comment: Gotta admit I'm not a fan of that format. The elvis-operator is great (not in vimscript, unfortunately) but that "or" syntax is non-intuitive...kind of "gross" lol. What languages are you a regular user of? Javascript? Python? (Just curious...nothing to do with an answer. :)

Comment: @BLayer yes exactly both, and bash.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from `8.2.1794` vim has `null coalescing operator` aka `falsy operator`

```
let value = somevar ?? othervar ?? 100
```

`:h ??`

```
The expression before the '??' is evaluated.  If it evaluates to
|truthy|, this is used as the result.  Otherwise the expression after the '??'
is evaluated and used as the result.  This is most useful to have a default
value for an expression that may result in zero or empty: >
    echo theList ?? 'list is empty'
    echo GetName() ?? 'unknown'
```

Neovim uses quite an old vimscript so there is a doubt it would ever have this provided it is focused on lua.

There is also `get` function that could be used for cases like:

```
" my_var = g:my_var if it is defined, 100 otherwise
let my_var = get(g:, "my_var", 100)

" my_var = s:my_var if it is defined, 100 otherwise
let my_var = get(s:, "my_var", 100)
```

Comment: not working on neovim (also vim from what I see).

Comment: and `get(` doesn't help me because it only retrieves item from a list

Comment: next time specify neovim in the question pls, @Moshe. This operator is in recent vim 8.2.1794

Comment: as for `get(` it works for `g:`, `b:`, `s:`, `l:` and `t:` variables